# iPod tells me to log in to iTunes account on a computer. What next?

Tags: ipod

But I am already loged in to my iTunes account and keep getting an error where my iPod tells me to log in to iTunes account on a computer

---

I had originally pluged my ipod in to the computer as it would give me this message and not let me update my apps.  Once pluged in it told me there was ipod updates so i installed them.  In that process it told me there was a problem with my ipod and that i had to set it to factory settings.  So needless to say, i was not happy about losing all that i had on my ipod!  But still now it gives me the same message.  I deauthorized and reauth computer and i thought that worked as it let me uppdate an app and add a new app.  But then as i started to build my app selection again it would still from time to time tell me i need to log in to my itunes on my computer before the app could be added (even though i am still loged in).  This is the same computer, and connection i have always used for this ipod.  Now that i am at work i am using my Wi-Fi here and i have been able to add apps with NO problems!  So what could be causing the problem at home all of the sudden??

Comment: Here is a great link to world wide support to help troubleshoot this - http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/ww/

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything right. Sometimes an error on the other end (apple's servers) can look like a local problem to iTunes. Most of the time, what you did would have fixed this.

Have you considered getting a hand from the billing / account people that work for Apple? Start with the [Account & Billing](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/) section on the left...

Your computer needs the OK from Apple's on line servers to fix the errors. This is an account issue and you don't have to pay for this support (but may have to start by emailing apple if no one is free when you ask for help).

You could try authorizing your account on any iOS device or another computer to rule out problems with your online account as well.

If you get errors on your computer after you re-authorize, you might have to go through this article on [iTunes repeatedly prompts to authorize computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1389) to fix things. If the iPod is giving the error, be sure to restore the iPod (which will wipe everything that's not backed up) to get the new authorization to take on the iPod.

Comment: Help from billing?  It's an ipod though not a iphoone so there is no charges...thanks for reply!!  Hopefully it will fix its self. what would happen if i deleted my iTunes act from home and set us a new one?  would that mess up my iPod?

Comment: When you reauthorized your iTunes - that prevents it from now on moving purchased content to your iPod. (it probably was broken before you deauthorized) you _must_ get a successful authorization token from the online iTunes server before you can use the content on iTunes or transfer it to any iPod. This is why iTunes deleted the apps and music - that's what happens on a sync when authorization is no longer valid.

Comment: So how come on my work Wi-Fi i have no issues downloading anything? (and no as you can likely tell i am not very tech inclined LOL)

Comment: I love that you aren't tech inclined - it forces me to really think about how to answer since I can't fall back on your familiarity with how things actually work to address any shortcomings in my answer. :-) (It does mean you might need to join the chat for some guidance or get a human to walk you through things - Q/A like this site isn't the best for working out a common language or troubleshooting the many causes to this.)

Comment: And since you're new here - you can click on the link by the edited to see what I changed in the answer as I learn more about the problem. http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/23613/revisions